# Hibernate: One-2-One & Many-2-One equality if one of participants has only final string fileds (something like stateless)

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

***What I have***

There are two entities `A` and `B`. `B` is staless, or it's right to say it has only final string fields. There are `many-2-one` relationship between `A` and `B` appropriatelly.

***What I want:***

I want to leave `B` stateless. Means I don't want to make `many-2-one` bidirectional relationship and add `List<A>` field into my `B` class.

***Question:***

*If `B` is stateless, is it right to make `one-2-one` unidirectional relationship between them? (means from `A` to `B`)*

***EDIT (how can I have a stateless entity):***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table")
public class Class {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Column(name = "name")
    private final String name;

    @Column(name = "badgeColor")
    private final String badgeColor;

    public ProfileState(String name, String badgeColor) {
        this.name = name;
        this.badgeColor = badgeColor;
    }
    //getters
}
```

***EDIT 2 (why unidirectional):***

I can't make it bidirectional, because due to app logic there should be only one instance of `B` entity. Due to the same logic, `B` is a singleton, and it can't have a reference to single `A` entity. If it has, it should have references to all `A` entities. But `B` isn't a singleton in common sense. So if it will be `many-to-one` relatioship, I should synchronize each entity of `B` class.

Comment: How can you have a stateless entity?  That seems fundamentally contradictory, entities are used to persist state.

Comment: For what I need such entity? Actually it's something like singleton. In Hibernate singleton is impossible (in terms of Singleton Patter). So I decide to set `className` to id, and due to the fact that my entity is stateless I have the same singleton. Means I can't store in DB two entities of specific class

Comment: That's not what stateless means.  To answer your question, whether in this scenario you should make a one to one relationship bidirectional it is entirely up to you and should be driven from your data model and its expected usage.  Often, making a relationship bidirectional is more about usage than some abstract conceptual reasoning.

Comment: Singleton is different too

Comment: Ok, I have a `B` entity with final state. Is it right to make an unidirectional one-2-one relatioship&

Comment: SEe my above, whether a relationship should be unidirectional or bidirectional is going to depend on the specific semantics and usage of your data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use an unidirectional many to one relation from A to B?

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="TABLE_B_ID")
```

Comment: Because I can't store any state in my `B` class!

Comment: You can set the cascade type to don't persist whatever changes you make on B unless you explicitely persist that entity

Comment: I can't. There may be a dozen asynchronous operations on `B` entites, including link different `A` entities to the same `B` entity. So if I have a bidirectional relationship, I have to synchronize each instance of `B` with one another.

Comment: I don't know if i am not understanding something, but that's the reason why i say unidirectional relationship from A to B, yo don't specify the relation from B to A, so your work would be done only over A's entitys. B remains unawuare of changes and synchronization.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. But in such case I need @OneToOne from `A` to `B`